# Find sum of all the records for a specific index name in a panda pivot table dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

I have panda pivot table dataframe like below:

```
Account ACC1    ACC2    ACC3    GRAND TOTAL
Product             
PROD1   2       3       4       9
PROD2   3       5       7       15
REFUND  2       3       8       13
```

In pivot table code I used `index = "Product"` and `margins_name="GRAND TOTAL".`

I want to find the sum of refund, how can I do that? Or "GRAND TOTAL" value for index name="REFUND" which is "13".
I used below to create pivot table:

```
 df_pivot = pd.pivot_table(df1,values="cost",index = "Product", columns="Account",
                       margins = True, margins_name="GRAND TOTAL",aggfunc=np.sum,fill_value=0)
```

Comment: `df_pivot.loc['REFUND']` ? if not , please provode the full code to recreate the pivot table(including the original df)

Comment: I provided the pivot table creation code @anky_91

Comment: 1: did my code in comment not work? 2: if not provide us the original df from which you created the pivot too

Comment: getting error: "['Grand Total'] not found in axis"

Comment: then point 2 :) Bdw `GRAND TOTAL` is already there in pivot df, no sure where are you getting confused

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use .loc to select row then column and retrieve the value.

```
df_pivot.loc['REFUND',"GRAND TOTAL"]
```

Example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"A": ["foo", "foo", "foo", "foo", "foo",
                         "bar", "bar", "bar", "bar"],
                   "B": ["one", "one", "one", "two", "two",
                         "one", "one", "two", "two"],
                   "C": ["small", "large", "large", "small",
                         "small", "large", "small", "small",
                         "large"],
                   "D": [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
                   "E": [2, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 8, 9, 9]})
table = pd.pivot_table(df, values='D', index=['A'],
                    columns=['C'], margins = True, margins_name="GRAND TOTAL",aggfunc=np.sum,fill_value=0)

table

C          large    small   GRAND TOTAL
A           
bar           11       11       22
foo            4        7       11
GRAND TOTAL   15       18       33

table.loc['foo',"GRAND TOTAL"]
11
```

Comment: I did this, getting error: ""['Grand Total'] not found in axis""

Comment: in your example, grand total is full caps e.g. 'GRAND TOTAL', not 'Grand Total'